# Error executing 'dotnet ~.dll' in auto-start on boot in Raspberry pi 4 linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

```
[09:43:46 INF] Application Starting
SerialPort1: OnStatusChanged -> connection closed
SerialPort1: OnStatusChanged -> connection closed
SerialPort1: OnStatusChanged -> /dev/ttyUSB0: 115200 bps, 8N1, no handshake
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Bad file descriptor
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Interop.CheckIo(Int64 result, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at System.ConsolePal.Read(SafeFileHandle fd, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ConsolePal.UnixConsoleStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
   at System.IO.SyncTextReader.ReadLine()
   at System.Console.ReadLine()
   at AV308XC.GreetingService.Run() in C:\KDSONG\Project\SKD\2021-08 - AVISS - MEMS SENSOR\AV308XC\GreetingService.cs:line 220
   at AV308XC.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\KDSONG\Project\SKD\2021-08 - AVISS - MEMS SENSOR\AV308XC\Program.cs:line 34
```

I try to make a .dll file start on boot in Raspberry pi 4 linux, adding this command in rc.local file.

```
dotnet /home/pi/E6101/AV308XC/AV308XC.dll &
```

I heard it worked well in Rasberry pi 3 linux but in some reason it doesn't work here. I've tried many ways like using 'systemd' but only to find out that this dll file does work in Raspberry pi 4 if I execute in terminal, but doesn't work if I try to start it indirectly(?).
The purpose of that dll file is to make a contact with the clouding system and repeat the sending data and receiving respond from the server. Most of the indirect ways failed this and the connection closed instantly.
Message above is part of a log file from nohup command. I used nohup command because I thaught this problem caused because it should run without the terminal. So as it failed I started to think for some reason it doesn't work in background. But if I execute this command

```
dotnet /home/pi/E6101/AV308XC/AV308XC.dll &
```

in terminal it seems to be working well. Although log of sending and responding message doesn't pop up, may because it's working in background, at least the process doesn't shut down. I got frustrated at this point. UnauthorizedAccessException...

So my question is , is there a way to solve this problem or I heard this dll file made from window system so do I need to recompile this file's saurce code on this linux system?

Comment: `System.Console.ReadLine()` shouldn't be used in a service. There's no console attached to them, which probably causes the error.

Comment: That means as the service runs on background shell not from console so no console to attach? And that caused the IO error? If so than do you know why does it worked on Raspberry pi 3 but not on Raspberry pi 4?

Comment: Plus  what is the exact meaning of 'service' here? Does it includes scripts and other programs in rc.local?  Or everything that could be found with 'service' command?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, as you didn't show any code. By service I mean background process. Please show a minimum reproducible sample.

Comment: I finally found out what you were tring to say! `System.Console.ReadLine()` really was a problem. It should wait before conneting to server but as it's not running on console it just passes to next step. So no specific error or anything like that occurs. Thank you very much!!